# Defining a typedef with the constructor in c

Tags: c, windows, constructor, macros

I'm writing a project. This project will be injected into another program and will enable that program to write CRUD operations on the files it wants. The constructor I wrote in my project will take a struct (data) from the injected program and define it as a type with typedef (like '`typedef struct Book_ Entity`'). It will then do all of its operations over this type. However, the point where I stuck is this: After declaring an Entity with typedef, I wrote '`typedef type_t Entity;`' in the Constructor macro I wrote. the line of code does not work or is valid only within the macro. You can better understand what the problem is from the program below.

NOTE: The data_num in data_constructor tells how many variables the data consists of. Required for Delete and Update operations.

Part of Constructors.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef CONSTRUCTORS
    #define CONSTRUCTORS

    #define DATA_CONSTRUCTOR
    typedef Entity;
    #define data_constructor(type_t, number_of_data) typedef type_t Entity; int data_num = number_of_data;

    #define FILE_CONSTRUCTOR
    inline void file_constructor(const char* path) 
    {
        char* g_file_path;
        strcpy(g_file_path, path);
    } 
#endif
```

The constructor I wrote above is included. It defines the data structure (such as '`struct Book_'`) received from the user as a type. I got an error like `expected 'Entity' {aka 'int'} but argument is of type 'struct Book_'` when I ran the program while waiting for a structure like `'typedef struct Book_ Entity'`.

Part of InMemoryDal.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Constructors.h"
#include "Defines.h"
#include "FileHelper.h"

#ifndef IN_MEMORY_H
#define IN_MEMORY_H
#endif

extern char *g_file_path;
extern int data_num;

FILE *g_file;
FILE *g_temp_file;

void Add(Entity entity);
void Delete(Entity entity);
void Update(Entity entity);

void Add(Entity entity)
{
    F_OPEN(g_file, g_file_path, MODE_AB);
    F_WRITE(&entity, sizeof(Entity), 1, g_file);
    fclose(g_file);
}
```

This is where I write the functions of the program. Here, the Add () function takes an Entity type entity from the user and prints it to the file. Macros such as F_OPEN and F_WRITE used in it are defined in another file. It is just below in the file.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef MODES
    #define MODE_W "w"
    #define MODE_R "r"
    #define MODE_WB "wb"
    #define MODE_RB "rb"
    #define MODE_A "a"
    #define MODE_AB "ab"
#endif

#define TEMP_FILE_PATH "temp_file.txt"

#define F_OPEN(fp, f_path, mode) fp=fopen(f_path, mode); if(fp == NULL) exit(1);
#define F_WRITE(buffer, element_size, element_count, fp) fwrite(buffer, element_size, element_count, fp); if(fwrite==0) exit(1);
```

Here is the code I tested the program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "InMemoryDal.h"

struct Book_
{
    int id;
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    int print_number;
};

int main()
{
    data_constructor(struct Book_, 4);
    file_constructor("\\test123.txt");

    struct Book_ b;
    b.id=1;
    strcpy(b.title, "testname");
    strcpy(b.author, "testauthor");
    b.print_number=34;
    Add(b);

    return 0;
}
```

I think I explained my problem well. I want your help to set up the constructor structure I want. Thanks!

Comment: The compiler says you passed a Book_ to a function that's declared with an Entity argument (not a Book_ argument). Can you explain why you expected that to work?

Comment: If you want to understand, you can try to get the code generated by the preprocessor after macro expansion. Also the F_WRITE macro may not work (it does not get the result of fwrite in a variable to test it, but test a function name)

Comment: This is what I want. In other words, the user will be able to work with the struct structure he wants. So I want to pass the Entity alias to the struct the user has entered. Otherwise I will only be able to work with one specific struct, not any struct. @user253751

Comment: @Ptit Xav - I could not understand how to do it. Can you explain in a little more detail? Thanks...

Comment: @Dagbfaith Where is the part that makes the user able to work with the struct structure he wants?

Comment: As you use Entity in your functions , you should also define b as an Entity . May be better to use data_constructor outside of main.. Also in file_constructor you copy a string in an undefined memory location.

Comment: `typedef` doesn't change anything, it just lets you call the same type by a different name. `Book_` isn't the same as `int` even if you called it `Entity` both times.

Comment: The point I don't understand is that the `typedef struct Book_ Entity` statement works normally. However, when I do this with #define, I get an error when it should work again. Why is that? So do macros (just like functions) define variables, typedefs (...) defined in local? If so, how am I going to define this Entity. (NOTE: I am trying to build such a structure inspired by the structure I use in C #.). Also, a point I don't understand is: `typedef Entity;` a definition or a declaration? Thanks

Comment: 'May be better to use data_constructor outside of main' I could not understand how to do this. Can you explain a little more? thanks. @PtitXav

Comment: This is a problem of logic : you need to define Entity in some UserSpecific.h file to be able to do sizeof(Entity) . This file could be where you define the typedef struct and also define a macro for number_of_data. then include this .h file in all .c files.I know it is different that what you planned to do.